# Decide whether the $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$ is rational

Tags: number-theory, radicals, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

Working needs to be shown
$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$
My guess is to multiply by  $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$ then we have a rational number but is it enough to prove the rationality of a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$ is rational, then so is $\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}}$ and consequently $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}\in \mathbb Q$.

The sum of two rational numbers is a rational number, thus $\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}\right)+\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}\right)\in \mathbb Q$.

Proceed.

Comment: Dont get the first implication

Comment: Multiply the given number by $1\color{grey}{=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}-(5^{1/2}-2)^{1/2}}}$. Excuse the stupid notation, mathjax won't render the code properly.

Comment: but what if i will assume that the number is irrational?

Comment: @kazinsky It either is rational or irrational. If it is rational, the above gives a contradiction, therefore it must be irrational. If it is irrational, then it is irrational. In either case you conclude it is irrational.